# How often is type declaration necessary in Julia for optimal performance?

Tags: types, julia

I have started translating from python a game engine for a boardgame I have invented. I know that the example I am going to show is pretty meaningless, there is no real need to optimize it, but I would like to get this right before dealing with the heavy functions.

```
function howMany()::Int8
    pieces::Int8 = 0
    while pieces > 8 || pieces < 4
        try
            print("How many pieces are we going to play with (min 4, max 8)? ")
            pieces = parse(Int8, readline(STDIN))
        catch
            println("It must be an integer number between 4 and 8!")
        end
    end
    return pieces
end

function main()
    pieces::Int8 = howMany()
    #println(pieces, typeof(pieces))
end

main()
```

Is it necessary to declare Int8 4 times (3 declaration + parse parameter)?
When can I avoid specifying Int8 without having any performance trade off?

Comment: @DanGetz has provided a great answer. I thought I would just add that personally I prefer to include type information in the function signature, eg `myfunc(x::Float64)::Int`, *even though it usually isn't necessary to do so to get type stable code*. The reason is that it makes life easier when you come back and look at the code 6 months later, plus it can make life easier from a debugging perspective (ie you get a very interpretable error if you ever try to feed the wrong type into the function, or alter the function and accidentally output the wrong type)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twice in the following which avoids expensive `try-catch`:

```
function howMany()
    while true
        print("How many pieces are we going to play with (min 4, max 8)? ")
        pieces = get(tryparse(Int8, readline(STDIN)), Int8(0))
        4 <= pieces <= 8 && return pieces
        println("It must be an integer number between 4 and 8!")
    end
end

function main()
    pieces = howMany()
    println(pieces, typeof(pieces))
end

main()
```

Uses nice short-cuts such as:

- `get` with default
- short-circuit `&&` instead of bulkier `if ... end`.

And it is code-stable as `@code_warntype howMany()` shows.

Comment: Thanks! So, are you telling me that since the function always returns a value of the same type, it is not necessary to add `::Int8` neither to `pieces` (both times) nor to `howMany()`  (performance-wise speaking)?

Comment: Exactly. It is always good to keep in mind, that once compiled, everything is typed. Hence, leaving out types makes the compiler have to think about them, and Julia's type inference is decent enough to know `howMany()` returns an Int8 and after `pieces = someInt8` then `pieces` is an Int8.